# Host Windows computer for a home automation system

Tags: windows, smart-home

I have a home automation software solution targeting .NET (Windows). It currently works with Insteon devices, utilizing their 2413U USB PLM, which interfaces to a host computer as an emulated serial (COM) port, physically connected via USB-A. I am currently using an old Microsoft Surface Pro 2 (~2013 vintage) but the time is coming that I need to investigate a replacement.

Criteria:

- Runs Windows (10 or 11) can be IoT edition.
- x86 preferred but not essential provided all other criteria can be met
- Supports virtual COM over USB
- USB-A port
- Low cost

Nice to have:

- Built-in battery (as in tablet) - capable of "riding out" brief power interruptions (<10 min) without need of an external UPS.

The solution places minimal demands on CPU, storage, and memory (a few MB storage, about 50MB memory footprint).

Comment: That narrows it down to a laptop or a surface replacement.

Comment: If you only look at the criteria you can get a self-built desktop for about €300 but if you want the built in battery you are looking for a laptop and those cost a minimal of €500

Comment: @Irsu85 I was thinking about one of those mini-PCs (approaching the form factor of a Raspberry PI) except I'm not aware of any such equipped with a battery - unless I've missed something. Point is, it would probably operate headless most of the time.

Comment: Those are also possible yea, but desktops and miniPCs generally don't have batteries inside, for that you need to follow Rohit's answer and go laptop (except maybe the second hand Framework without screen)

Comment: A raspberry Pi running Debian Gnu/Linux. Meets the requirements: It has a windowing system. It supports serial over USB (no setup), 4 usb A ports, Low cost, runs .net, can get UPS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at PC on a stick.  If you search for "PC Sticks" you will find many.  I have not used this one, but it seems to be a good match for you

[HEIGAOLAPC Mini PC Stick](https://www.amazon.com.au/HEIGAOLAPC-Windows-Computer-Business-Industrial/dp/B0C6X1TK98/ref=sr_1_3?ascsubtag=wp-nz-2724504232193810000-22&keywords=AIOEXPC%2BPC%2Bstick&sr=8-3&th=1)

Windows 11 Pro,Intel Celeron J4125 8GB DDR4 RAM 128GB eMMC Fanless Mini Computer,Dual WiFi 6.0/BT5.2/4K HD/USB PD3.0 Business Office Industrial IOT Media Home Small Computer

- It takes 12V DC, so you can wire it to a battery
- Has a mixture of USB sockets
- Its not too expensive

[image]